# Bad Request while authenication in bot sdk4 using own generic oauth 2 connection string

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework

We have used our own generic oauth 2 authentication for verifying user. 
After clicking sign in its redecting to login page(bot popup) but while returning to bot its always giving Bad Request.

Sending request from bot to application(post):-
client_id=12352&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect&scope=&state=ccd1dcf683044447a1fed78ed6828ba1

Returning request from application to bot(get):-
https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirectcode=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYW5qaTU0MyIsIm5iZiI6MTU0Mzg5OTEzNiwiZXhwIjoyNTM0MDIyODEwMDAsImlzcyI6IkNTUEwiLCJhdWQiOiJFdmVyeW9uZSJ9.mLEbu06qlBsLY6hODY-YtmPNU2EaAfdFF0PPlHMKgb8[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCZQF.png)&state=ccd1dcf683044447a1fed78ed6828ba1

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Did you find the root cause ? I have an IdentityServer for authorization, using AAD as authentication, and I get the same. No way to get some logs from bot framework endpoint...

Comment: Actually my problem came from the fact that I was using a self-signed certificate for my authorization service.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with the authorization/Token/Refresh URLs you're calling for your token.

I set up a generic OAuth 2 using imgur for the authentication and it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: i am able to connect with third party providers(google,fb,github..) but i want to check the credentials with my database. for this i have used identity server4 but coludn't connect same posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829248/ms-bot-authentication-with-identity-server4-generic-oauth2)