# MS Bot Authentication with Identity Server4 (generic oauth2)

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We are implementing a bot application which requires authentication with database.
I want to use identity server for oauth token generation and connect with database.

When I try to authenticate with bot its always giving bad request exception and I am not getting any additional information. I able to authenticate with third party providers (google,fb,github..).

I followed some links of customizing identity server with own database but not able to authenticate with bot.

https://davidmatablog.wordpress.com/2018/07/19/securing-dotnetcore-2-1-web-api-with-identityserver4/

[How to use existing DB with IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385422/how-to-use-existing-db-with-identityserver4)

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4703

https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/

Comment: There is no information that could help solve the problem. Add [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and other helpful information.

Comment: Here the same question i posted using custom authentication but its not working. so i want to use identity server server for bot authentication(oauth string - generic oauth 2) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606838/bad-request-while-authenication-in-bot-sdk4-using-own-generic-oauth-2-connection)

Comment: Any update ? I'm having an issue as well with a custom IdentityServer backed with AzureAD authentication. When using Generic OAuth2, I get a Bad request from the Bot Framework redirect Uri

Comment: Actually the problem came from the fact that I was using a self-signed certificate for my authorization service.

Comment: We are using AAD B2C and are unable to finish the OAuth. has anyone else gotten this to work with B2C?